# WebView Not Loading webpage

Tags: android, html

I have a `WebView` and I want to store a webpage locally and open it on startup. But it's giving me the following error:

`The Requested file was not found 123.html`
maybe this is because i have two "mWebView.loadUrl".
I was unable to solve this problem because I'm new to Eclipse and Java, any help will be appreciated!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Browser extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/123.html");
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
        {
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have placed 123.html in your `/assets/` directory?

Comment: its in the "assets" folder

Comment: Well, that is weird. It should work. Double check the filename and folder location, and try cleaning your project via Project/Clean. Also no need to load the google homepage first, remove that call.

Comment: i tripple checked it, i have also many other html files lying in the same folder , all are opening but not this one

Comment: Tried renaming it and seeing if you can access it via the new name?

Comment: i removed that call but the html page should load at least otherwise it will be useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the location `file:///android_asset/123.html` does not exist.
Either put a real URL or check if this file really exists and on this location.

Comment: its in the "assets" folder

Comment: Try to debug it with:
`new File("file://android_assets").list()`
to see which files there is on this directory..
Or
Try "file://assets/123.html" instead

Comment: DO YOU MEAN "asset" ??

Comment: "file://assets/123.html" OR "file:///asset/123.html"

Answer (score 1):

You need a project sctructure like this:

```
src
  -- java files
rs
  -- resource files
assets
  123.html
```

your html file must be inside the folder assets.

more info in http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: its in the "assets" folder